# Retrieve specific value by using Selenium C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="span9">
<div class="validation-summary-errors" data-valmsg-summary="true">
    <ul>
        <li>asdf</li>
        <li>dfg</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to retrieve the value "dfg" in relation to selenium for unit testing by using C# code.

```
    IWebElement ddd = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("validation-summary-errors"));

    IList<IWebElement> ddd3d = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//validation-summary-errors/ul/li"));
```

I have tried to retrieve the value but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Info:
*In this context I cannot add any html, css or javascript code. cshtml because it is created automatically by asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.validation-summary-errors>ul>li:nth-child(2)")).Text;
```

this will return the string dfg. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about IWebElement but on first glance I'd say that your xpath is incorrect,  try:   "//div/ul/li"

Answer (score 0):

ddd3d.Last().Text does not work?